# messy dataset columnnames to row and ordering values R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm a litte desprate, not even have an idea how to work the following:
My dataframe looks like the follwoing:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
          `01.02`= c(4,4,4,4),
           BK= seq(1,4,1),
           GK= c(3,2, NA, 4),
          `02.02`= c(1,2,3,4),
            BK= seq(2,5,1),
            GK= c(2,1, 6, 4))
```

(in my orginal dataset I do not have the (X in front of the dates, and the BK, and GK is not named with the suffix .1 etc.)

The dataframe I want looks like:

```
df1 <- data.frame("BK A" = c(1,2),
                 "GK A" =c(3, 2),
                 "BK B" =c(2,3),
                 "GK B" =c(2,1),
                 "BK C" =c(3,4),
                 "GK C"=c(NA, 6),
                 "BK D"= c(4,5),
                  "GK D" =c(4,4),
                 Date = c("01.02", "02.02" ))
```

So I want to create a new column where all the columnnames which contain a date (e.g. 01.02) is a new observation (the values of those columns in df can be dropped).
The new columnnames shall be combinations out of the Column name, and the name of the BK/ GK columns. The Values shall be those in correspondes in the df$BK df$GK columns.

As further explanation: df[3] and df[4] belongs to df[2] and df[6] and df[7] belongs to df[4].

Anyone have an Idea? I tried some with reshape but this gets me somewhere wrong....

**EDIT**:
In My Orginal Dataframe there is One more BK Columne which easly can get deleted, since there are only NA in them.

```
First several Lines of my original df: 
> head(str(Berlin))
tibble [87 × 104] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Aktie : chr [1:87] "NA   NA %" "Preuß. Freiwillige Anleihe   4.5 %" "Neue Preuß. Schuldverschr. Von 1850   4.5 %" "so von 1852   4.5 %" ...
 $ 02.01.: num [1:87] NA 4.5 4.5 4.5 4 3.5 NA NA 4.5 3.5 ...
 $ BK    : num [1:87] NA 100.5 100.8 100.8 99.2 ...
 $ GK    : num [1:87] NA NA 100.2 100.2 98.8 ...
 $ BK    : logi [1:87] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

dput(Berlin[1:4, 1:7])
structure(list(Aktie = c("NA   NA %", "Preuß. Freiwillige Anleihe   4.5 %", 
"Neue Preuß. Schuldverschr. Von 1850   4.5 %", "so von 1852   4.5 %"
), `02.01.` = c(NA, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5), BK = c(NA, 100.5, 100.75, 
100.75), GK = c(NA, NA, 100.25, 100.25), BK = c(NA, NA, NA, NA
), `03.01.` = c(NA, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5), BK = c(NA, 100.5, 100.75, 
100.75)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you explain why GK A is 4,3 and GK B 4,4 ?

Comment: Also, where did `C` and `D` from `df` gone in `df1`?

Comment: sorry my fault. @Basti: I corrected the numbers sorry I got a little messed up. The Numbers comes from The Columns df$BK df$GK after the corresponding "date" Columns in df.

Comment: @Francesco Grosetti : Sorry I skiped. I just added those as well.

Comment: Could you run your code defining `df` adding the argument `check.names = FALSE` and see if that matches your actual data? (Or more simply share the data using `dput()`...)

Comment: @Gregor Thomas: It does. For deput() the data st to big to give some usefule insights i guess. I Edit. the head of str() to the orginal post in a second.

Comment: You can use `dput` on the same subset of data that you shared, e.g., `dput(df[1:4, 1:7])` for 4 rows and 7 columns.